# How can I fix or reset JSFiddle panels?

Tags: jsfiddle

I seem to have done something wrong on JsFiddle and can't figure out how to fix it.  The panels are out of place (see image below).  I've tried "empty cache and hard reload" but that did not work.

Any ideas on how to fix or reset the panels?  I'm using Chrome on Windows 10.

[image: broken fiddle]